# Magento 2.3.4. Product Description tab is missing

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, frontend, tabs

I am using a custom theme by Swissup on my Magento store. The code that used to get all the product related tabs is `$block->prepareTabsData()` Strangely enough, this is now returning  all the tabs except 'Product Description' which is the first to appear before `feature` tab. Is there an alternative function to retrieve the tabs? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed when our theme from a third part was updated. We are using Argento Luxury from SwissUp.